# use sprintf with a vector rather than a variable number of arguments in R

Tags: r, printf

I would like to use the `sprintf` function in R with a variable number of arguments.  Can I bundle these arguments together in a character vector or list in order to avoid supplying these arguments to `sprintf` individually?

An example will clarify:

```
base_string = "(1) %s, (2) %s, (3) %s"
sprintf(base_string, "foo", "bar", "baz") # this works
sprintf(base_string, c("foo", "bar", "baz")) # this doesn't work
```

In Python I can accomplish this with

```
base_string = "(1) %s, (2) %s, (3) %s"
base_string % ("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We can use `do.call`

```
do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = base_string, as.list(v1)))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("foo", "bar", "baz")
```