# how to print a variable number of arguments in r?

Tags: r, printf, variadic-functions

new to r. this question has answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368802/can-you-pass-a-vector-to-a-vararg-vector-to-sprintf?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121200/use-sprintf-with-a-vector-rather-than-a-variable-number-of-arguments-in-r).

But these do not seem answer the question in the case of:

```
vec <- c("a","b","c","d")
s<-do.call(sprintf, c(list("%s %s"), vec))
```

The [doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/sprintf) says: " ... The arguments (including fmt) are recycled if possible a whole number of times to the length of the longest, and then the formatting is done in parallel. ... "

The code below shows that this is not happening:

```
> vec <- c("a","b","c","d")
> s<-do.call(sprintf, c(list("%s %s"), vec))
> print(s)
[1] "a b"
> v1 <- c("foo", "bar", "baz","foo", "bar", "baz")
> base_string = "%s, %s, %s"
> s<-do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = base_string, as.list(v1)))
> print(s)
[1] "foo, bar, baz"
>
```

How do i make this print out all of the values?

Edit: according to @mt1022, i misread the doc. he suggests: sprintf(paste0(v1, collapse = ' ')) which works.

Thanks to @chinsoon12 for the hint.

What I really want to do is something like this:

```
> s<-NA
> v<-c(1,"2",pi,2,"foo",2*pi)
> s<-do.call(sprintf, c(v, list(fmt=paste(rep("%d %s %f", length(v)/3), collapse=" "))))
Error in (function (fmt, ...)  : 
  invalid format '%d'; use format %s for character objects
> print(s)
[1] NA
>
```

The answer (thanks to @mt1022) is to use a list instead of a vector:

```
v<-list(1,"2",pi,2,"foo",2*pi)
s<-do.call(sprintf, c(v, list(fmt=paste(rep("%d %s %f", length(v)/3), collapse=" "))))
```

Comment: r u looking for `do.call(sprintf, c(vec, list(fmt=paste(rep("%s", length(vec)), collapse=" "))))`?

Comment: something like that. please see edit.

Comment: You can not hold both characters and numerals in a vector otherwise the numerals will be coerced to characters. You can keep those values with a list like `v <- list(1,"2",pi,2,"foo",2*pi)`. Then your `sprintf` command should work.

Comment: works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc is right. In first case, `do.call(sprintf, c(list("%s %s"), vec))` is equal to:

```
sprintf("%s %s", "a","b","c","d")
```

The fmt string `"%s %s"` requires two vectors while you provided four and the last two ("c", "d") were not used for printing.

The second case is similar. `do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = base_string, as.list(v1)))` is equal to:

```
sprintf(fmt = "%s, %s, %s", "foo", "bar", "baz","foo", "bar", "baz")
```

Three variables were to be printed based on `fmt` but you provided six.

---

Then, what does "recycled" in the doc mean?

and I guess you might misunderstand it. It means when the formating string and vectors are of different lengths, the short er ones will be recycled to the longest one. An example:

```
> sprintf(c('%s %s', '%s, %s'), c('a', 'b', 'c'), 1:6)
[1] "a 1"  "b, 2" "c 3"  "a, 4" "b 5"  "c, 6"
```

---

*How to print variable number of arguments*: You can try `paste`:

```
> sprintf(paste0(vec, collapse = ' '))
[1] "a b c d"
> sprintf(paste0(v1, collapse = ', '))
[1] "foo, bar, baz, foo, bar, baz"
```