# how to combine paste() and print() in the R language?

Tags: r, variadic-functions

I would like to combine the paste and print functions. This is the best I can do so far:

```
pp <- function(...) {
  s<-paste0(list(...), sep="")
}
foo<-"foo"
s<-paste0(foo,2,"bar",sep="")
print(s)
s2<-pp(foo,2,"bar")
print(s2) # how to remove spaces and quotes so it is like s?
```

Edit 1: Got it to work. Thank you:

```
pp <- function(...) {
  s<-paste0(list(...), collapse='')
  print(s)
}
```

Edit 2: Seems like this is a similar to an older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157455/how-to-print-a-variable-number-of-arguments-in-r) of  mine. I ended up with:

```
pn <- function(format="", ...) { # print
    s=sprintf(fmt=format,...)
    cat(s)
}
p <- function(format="", ...) { # priint line
    s=pn(format,...)
    cat(s,"\n")
}
x=1
y=2.3
z="4"
pn("x: %d, y: %f, z: %s",x,y,z)
pn()
pn("end")
p()
```

which seems to behave like what I am use to.

Comment: @ Ray Tayek: Hello! What is your expected output?

Comment: you could add `collapse = ''` to `paste` or if you used `pp <- function(...) {paste0(...)}` you wouldnt need it at all

Comment: removing sep= and trying collapse=''

Comment: i want both s's to be the same. i intend to put a print statement in pp().